# How to run a external class from controller passing context and UserManager as paremeters?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I am using asp.net mvc core 2.1 and need to run a external class from controller but passing parameter context for manipulate sql server and UserManager object because I want to get a specific claim from "User.Identities.First" command. Thank you in advance.

Comment: What did you try to achieve this?

Comment: Hi @Saadi ! I'm gonna set up a method in this external class to be executed on a recurring basis using Hangfire.

Comment: Can you share your some source code like where you are stuck and what did you try?

Comment: @Saadi I wasn't able to do anything because when I tried to run a controller inside Configure of Statup, I need to send dbContext and current user as parameters, because my controllers need that, then I don't know how to provide these paramenters in startup, I've tried to find out but I couldn't. Thanks for your interest.